# Аллокатор стандартной библиотеки

Tags: c++

Я пишу свою реализацию контейнера vector. Не могу разобраться с правильным перераспределением памяти. Ниже код, так я перезаписываю память сейчас, частично он взят из примера в интернете, так же из реализации vector. Мой вопрос в следующем: сейчас новые объекты при перезаписи конструируются и старые разрушаются, мне кажется это не логичным, почему нельзя менять указатель на объект, не трогая сам объект? Но сколько я ни пытался, у меня не получается это сделать и если код вообще компилируется, то появляются утечки. Буду благодарен объяснению или статье где затронуто перераспределение памяти на аллокаторе.

````
int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    std::string str = "jhrwebvkbekjvnkejnrvkjnekjrvnekjrvkjenrkjvnejkrnvkernvkjnerkvnekrjnvkjernvkjerv";
    std::allocator<std::string> alloc;

    std::allocator<std::string>::pointer start;
    std::allocator<std::string>::pointer end;

    start = alloc.allocate(n);
    end = start;

    //write
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        alloc.construct(end, str);
        end++;
    }


    std::allocator<std::string>::pointer new_start = alloc.allocate(n);
    std::allocator<std::string>::pointer new_end = new_start;

    //rewrite
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        alloc.construct(new_end, *(start + n));
        new_end++;
    }

    //free
    while(end != start)
    {
        alloc.destroy(end);
        end--;
    }
    alloc.destroy(end);
    alloc.deallocate(start, n);
    //free end

    start = new_start;
    end = new_end;

    //free
    while(end != start)
    {
        alloc.destroy(end);
        end--;
    }
    alloc.destroy(end);
    alloc.deallocate(start, n);
    //free end

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Я бы очень советовал для начала написать вектор без настройки аллокатора, на голом new и delete. Когда освоитесь, нацепить сверху аллокатор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ваши циклы с `destroy()` вылезают на 1 за границы массивов. Правильно так:

   ```
   while(end != start)
   {
       end--;
       alloc.destroy(end);
   }
   // Тут второй `destroy()` не нужен.
   ```
2. Опечатка: `*(start + n)` -> `*(start + i)`,
3. В C++20 из стандартного аллокатора были удалены `::pointer`, `.construct`, `.destroy` и прочее. Оставили `.allocate` и `.deallocate`.

   Правильно:

   - `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::string>>::pointer`
   - `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::string>>::construct(аллокатор, указатель, аргументы...)`
   - `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::string>>::destroy(аллокатор, указатель)`

---

> почему нельзя менять указатель на объект, не трогая сам объект?

Тут не очень понял. У объекта фиксированный адрес. Если хочется подвинуть его в в другое место, можно только создать новый объект, а старый удалить.

Comment: Получается, что объекты нужно заново пересоздавать, подругому не выйдет. У меня задание сделать вектор на 98 стандарте. Но на свой вопрос я ответ получил, спасибо!